# How do I make a floating window pop up when I click on a notification?

Tags: windows, notifications, popup, click, floating

When I click on the notification, I go to the activity I want to go to.
But if I click on the notification, it doesn't appear the floating window. How can I make appear the floating window if I click on the notification?

```
Intent intent2 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, TwoActivity.class);
intent2.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
PendingIntent pendingIntent2 = PendingIntent.getActivity(MainActivity.this, 0, intent2, 0);
int notifyId = 001;
NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
Notification.Builder mbuilder = new Notification.Builder(MainActivity.this);
mbuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon);
mbuilder.setContentTitle(_Title);
mbuilder.setContentText(_Content);
mbuilder.setDefaults( Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND | Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE);
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
    String channelId1 = "1";
    String channelName1 = "channel1";
    NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(channelId1, channelName1, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
    channel.enableLights(true);
    channel.setLightColor(Color.BLUE);
    channel.setShowBadge(true);
    channel.enableVibration(true);
    mbuilder.setChannelId(channelId1);
    if (mNotificationManager != null) {
        mNotificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
    }
} else {
    mbuilder.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND | Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS | Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE);
}
if (mNotificationManager != null) {
    mNotificationManager.notify(notifyId, mbuilder.build());
}
```